# Google Maps API Draw Order

Tags: google-maps, leaflet, kml, google-earth

I'm loading KML onto a web page with both Google Maps API and a plug-in for leaflet maps.

The KML typically has multiple routes in the form of pairs of linestrings.  The first linestring in the pair is a red line 6 pixels wide, the second is a white linestring 3 pixels wide.  This gives the effect of a white line with a red edge.

The kml looks like this...

```
<Style id="RedEdge"> 
    <LineStyle>
        <color>ff0000ff</color>
        <width>6</width>
    </LineStyle>
</Style>

<Style id="WhiteFill"> 
    <LineStyle>
        <color>ffffffff</color>
        <width>3</width>
    </LineStyle> 
</Style>

<Placemark>
    <name>Route of VR Tour</name>
    <styleUrl>#RedEdge</styleUrl>
    <LineString>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <coordinates>
            -3.266725,37.002497,1546.3 
            -3.266745,37.002502,1546.5
            -3.266743,37.00251,1546.5
            -3.266739,37.002544,1546.5 
            -3.266732,37.00262,1546.5 
            -3.266851,37.002646,1550 
        </coordinates>
    </LineString>
</Placemark>

<Placemark>
    <name>Route of VR Tour</name>
    <styleUrl>#WhiteFill</styleUrl>
    <LineString>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <coordinates>
            -3.266725,37.002497,1546.3
            -3.266745,37.002502,1546.5
            -3.266743,37.00251,1546.5 
            -3.266739,37.002544,1546.5
            -3.266732,37.00262,1546.5 
            -3.266851,37.002646,1550 
        </coordinates>
    </LineString>
</Placemark>
```

In Google Earth it is draw as one expects, 3px wide white on top of the 6 pixel wide red.

In the leaflet KML plug in the lines are draw as expected, 3px wide white on top of the 6 pixel wide red.

However when Google Maps API draws the line you only see a 6 pixel wide red line.

Invert the order of the lines in the KML, i.e. so that the white line appears ahead of the red line, and Google Maps API draws what we were hoping to see.

With this inverted order, Google Earth also draws what we wanted to see, but the plug-in for Leaflet maps draws only the red line (perhaps the white line is underneath, but you cannot tell).

So my question is how do we create a KML script which can produce a white line on top of the red line in Google Earth, Google Maps, and Leaflet Maps?

I have tried the <gx:drawOrder> tag, but it appears not to work in either Google Maps nor Leaflet Maps. Indeed, I'm not convinced it is working with Google Earth (Pro 7.3.4.8642 (64-bit)).

Likewise I played with <gx:outerColur> and <gx:outerWidth> tags, managed to get them to work in Google Earth, but had no luck with the Leaflet maps plug-in.

Your solutions much appreciated

Comment: One option that seems to work for the Google Maps JavaScript API v3 is the 3rd party parser [geoxml3](https://github.com/geocodezip/geoxml3): http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/SO_20220812_LineStringDrawOrder.kml (note that it will be less efficient for large KML than the native KmlLayer as it parses the KML in the browser and renders the polylines as `google.maps.Polyline` objects on the map)

Comment: Interesting, I'll take a look and try it out. Thank you.